# Cannot get a accurate aggregation count in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, go, aggregation-framework, mgo

So I have a large collection and I want to count the number of documents that all have the same `company_id` with other filters(either `expired_at` is greater than `new Date()` or `expired_at` doesn't exist in the document). Basically to count the number of active jobs belong to a company.

Here is what I have so far but the count result is way bigger than it should be. Can anybody tell me what is wrong with the query?

Maybe there are duplicates? If thats the case, how to group duplicates as one or avoid them when counting? Thanks.

```
db.jobs.aggregate([
{
    $match: {
        $and: [
            {company_id: ObjectId('524a09a44c9ff23382000037')},
            { $or: [ { expired_at: { $gt: new Date() } }, { expired_at: { $exists: false } } ]}
        ] 
    }
},
{
    $group: {
        _id: 1,   
        count: {$sum: 1}
    }
}
])
```

Actual code:

```
query := bson.M{
  "$and": []bson.M{
    bson.M{"company_id": id},
    bson.M{
      "$or": []bson.M{
        bson.M{"expired_at": bson.M{"$exists": false}},
        bson.M{"expired_at": bson.M{"$gt": bson.Now()}},
      },
    },
  },
}

counter := []bson.M{
  bson.M{"$match": query},
  bson.M{"$group": bson.M{"_id": 1, "count": bson.M{"$sum": 1}}},
}

var result struct {
  Count int `bson:"count"`
}
err := s.DB(session).C("jobs").Pipe(counter).One(&result)
```

This is what the schema looks like:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("52683eceda9f660e1e000011"),

    "activated_at" : ISODate("2014-05-30T09:18:40.961Z"),

    "url" : "http://blahblah/jobid3939799-public-sector-oracle-federal-financials-senior-associate-jobs",

    "job_category_ids" : [ 
        "Accounting/Auditing", 
        "Finance", 
        "Information Technology", 
        "Consulting"
    ],
    "location" : {
        "full_address" : "McLean, VA",
        "pts" : [ 
            -77.1772604, 
            38.9338676
        ]
    },
    "created_at" : ISODate("2013-10-23T21:25:34.262Z"),
    "ref_id" : "42927BR-0",

    "company_id" : ObjectId("524a09a44c9ff23382000037"),

    "updated_at" : ISODate("2014-05-30T09:18:41.085Z"),

    "expired_at" : ISODate("2014-05-31T09:21:30.357Z")
}
```

Comment: I think maybe your group should be "_id" : "$company_id".. That would group the results by companyId,.. Idk what a grouping of 1 does.

Comment: @reticentroot it returns the same count result

Comment: You might start printing out data to see where the dups are at, or to see what the real issue is.. Also take a look at the count operator https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/count/#pipe._S_count instead of using the $sum operator. It looks like with the count operator you can skip the group phrase and just worry about the match phase. If the value is still wrong then it's your matching not the grouping.

Comment: Also the way I do it in my code is `"total": bson.M{"$sum" :"$count}" ` in the group phase.